# Why "would" instead of "will" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, modal-verbs

> The goal for these negotiations is to reach **a mutually-agreed long-term comprehensive solution that *would* ensure Iranˈs nuclear program will be exclusively peaceful**. [(Source)](http://edition.cnn.com/2013/11/24/world/meast/iran-deal-text/)

what does would imply here? If it implies future, why *will* has not been used?

A good link teaching *would* thoroughly would be really appreciated. Specially, distinguishing between the senses of *would* is not always easy.

Comment: I would agree; _would_ is a hard word to fully understand. [This website](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-modal-would.htm) lists **11** different ways the word can be used.

Comment: @J.R. Yes I read the link. Now what do you think as a native *would* means here?

Comment: As a native, I would agree with swbarnes2. In this sentence, _would_ is just like _will_, only with a little uncertainty mixed in.

Comment: I have a link addressing 'would' and 'should' quite thoroughly:
http://www.bartleby.com/116/213.html
Someday I *should* read that text in full. (0:

Comment: You mentioned "would is just like will, only with a little uncertainty mixed in." I think that "would" is more certain than "could", am I right? @J.R.

Comment: @Zhanlong - Yes, that's correct; "could" is more like "maybe"; it's used for something that's a possibility, but not a certainty, and maybe even improbable.

Comment: BTW, swbarnes2 mentioned:"would" indicates that there is a strong doubt. Do you agree? If so, "would" equals to "could". @J.R.

Comment: @Zhanlong - That's not an easy question to answer, and it depends on context. (Remember there are many uses of the word _would_, as I said in my initial comment.) I could follow the structure found in the O.P.'s question, even without strong doubt: _"My goal is to get a steady job that would provide me with a steady income."_ The word _would_ is still appropriate to use there, even if we don't have any "strong doubt" about my employability or the job market. If we say: "The goal is to accomplish A that would achieve B," that simply means, "We can achieve B if we first accomplish A."

Comment: I'd argue that this is poor English. I would say 'that _will_ ensure Iran's nuclear program _is_ exclusively peaceful'

Comment: @Zhanlong: Dang! I should have checked before wasting time answering a second question about [*exactly the same sentence*](http://edition.cnn.com/2013/11/24/world/meast/iran-deal-text/)

Comment: I suggest you migrating your answer to that one. :) @FumbleFingers It's a good answer, better than the original one. Don't waste it.

Comment: @Zhanlong: I've asked the mods to merge the two questions. If that's not possible I think this one should actually be deleted, since the question text itself adds nothing to the original. If it *does* end up being deleted, I'll cut&paste my answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It seems to me that this is a *different* question. The last one asked Why *would*? -this one asks Why *will* in a *would* context? If the questions are merged, both questions (which you answer admirably) need to be preserved.

Comment: @StoneyB: Well, we certainly wouldn't want a *third* question on the same communiqué asking whether either or both verbs being looked at should be in the present tense! I was a bit surprised when I just checked and discovered that *neither* question bothered to cite the exact context. Since it is in fact *the full text of the nuclear deal between Iran and six world powers*, I think that's a pretty significant context! If nothing else, we can at least dismiss the idea that it's a "bad translation" or otherwise to be explained away as "poor English" for some reason.

Comment: @StoneyB I couldn't help but smiling at this minor difference. Good catch! I guess they are the same guy. Or, nima saw the last one in the first place. :-)

Comment: I think you nailed it on 'hammered out'. I think *will be peaceful* rather than *is peaceful* represents the US' aversion to any reading which could be taken to imply that the US concedes that Iran's program is **now** exclusively peaceful.

Comment: @StoneyB: Yes, I think we can be quite certain that the exact implications of all verb tenses and moods in such communiqués are likely to have been very carefully considered by many parties, all being (or at least, using the services of) extremely competent speakers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure you need a link explaining the full ins and outs of "would" in order to understand the answer to this question.

"Would" is (correctly) used in this sentence to express the fact that such a **mutually-agreed long-term comprehensive solution** does **not** currently exist, or at the very least, one has not been agreed upon. (This is a great example by the way, since various situations in Iran are/have been very difficult to resolve!)

We shouldn't use "will" (which would describe a concrete future), in cases such as these, where an outcome is very dependent on many factors (or conditions).

"Would" is the English language's conditional form. "Conditional" indicates that an outcome expressed with "would" is only possible if certain "conditions" are met. Think of "would" as "the furthest future possible".

I hope that at least answers your specific question.

To read more on "would", first check out its [primary definitions](http://thefreedictionary.com/would) (which give you some nice examples). [This article](http://www.englishpage.com/modals/would.html) also helps you on other aspects of this modal verb (past habits etc), and [this article](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-modal-would.htm) may also be of interest.

Comment: If "could" was used in this sentence, would "could" be less certain than "would"? Or would "could" be equivalent to "would" in this case? @JMB

Comment: "Would" is reliant on a different clause being true, in this case "reaching a ... solution", and indicates a definite outcome. "Could" implies that there is the *possibility* (...that Iranˈs nuclear program will be exclusively peaceful.)

Answer (score 4):

The difference in meaning is very slight, and I think "will" works okay in that sentence.  Based on my American dialect, I would prefer to use "will" when I think the thing in question is very likely to actually take place, and "would" indicates that there is a strong doubt.

So in your example, I think the odds of negotiation perfectly satisfying everyone are low, so I prefer "would" in that sentence.

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to the implications of the posted comment, I don't think there's any suggestion of "poor English" in using ***would*** rather than ***will*** in the first position within OP's cited context.

It's entirely a matter of stylistic choice whether they're seeking a solution that...

> *would ensure...
>
>    will ensure...
>
>    ensures...*

It's also largely just a matter of style whether that the aim is that Iranˈs nuclear program...

> *would be exclusively peaceful.
>
>    will be exclusively peaceful.*

...but it's probably fair to say ***is*** exclusively peaceful carries a stronger implication that Iran *already has an **ongoing** nuclear program*<sup>1</sup> (the two "conditional/future" alternatives might be slightly more likely if no such program yet exists).

Having said that, an utterance which "stacks/cascades" two consecutive conditional or future tense verb forms might well be considered unnecessarily complex and therefore somewhat clumsy.

Most native speakers would probably prefer to use present tense for at least one of the two positions in [OP's example](http://edition.cnn.com/2013/11/24/world/meast/iran-deal-text/). I've provided a link to the full context there, where I see no reason to take issue with any of the phrasing - it looks perfectly well written to me. The exact phrasing was probably hammered out over many hours of negotiation by many fluent speakers of English; repeated use of the conditional, which carries overtones of *this is all somewhat provisional and speculative* is quite natural in the context.

<sup>1</sup> Or, as per [StoneyB's comment,](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/28870/would-someone-please-tell-me-the-reason-for-using-will-and-would/28873#comment53564_28870) that the ongoing nuclear program is in fact "exclusively peaceful".

Comment: I do appreciate your support. Nevertheless, would anyone please answer my original question? I need the reason with sever logic.

Comment: @nima_persian: If by "my original question" you mean "Why don't both verbs use the same tense/mood?", I think the answer is that there's no particular reason why they *should*. The first one has as its subject a "hypothetical, future" ***solution***. In the second, the subject is a ***nuclear program***. Grammatically and logically they don't *need* to use the same tense. As I have pointed out, stylistically it's not so good to use the same "conditional/future" for both, and pragmatically there are strong arguments for the actual choice as made (I'm sure the exact phrasing was *negotiated*).

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the implications of [the posted comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/28870/would-someone-please-tell-me-the-reason-for-using-will-and-would/28873?noredirect=1#comment53545_28870)<sup>1</sup>, I don't think there's any suggestion of "poor English" in using ***would*** rather than ***will*** in the first position within OP's cited context.

It's entirely a matter of stylistic choice whether they're seeking a solution that...

> *would ensure...
>
>    will ensure...
>
>    ensures...*

It's also largely just a matter of style whether that the aim is that Iranˈs nuclear program...

> *would be exclusively peaceful.
>
>    will be exclusively peaceful.*

...but it's probably fair to say ***is*** exclusively peaceful carries a stronger implication that Iran *already has an **ongoing** nuclear program*<sup>2</sup> (the two "conditional/future" alternatives might be slightly more likely if no such program yet exists).

Having said that, an utterance which "stacks/cascades" two consecutive conditional or future tense verb forms might well be considered unnecessarily complex and therefore somewhat clumsy.

Most native speakers would probably prefer to use present tense for at least one of the two positions in [OP's example](http://edition.cnn.com/2013/11/24/world/meast/iran-deal-text/). I've provided a link to the full context there, where I see no reason to take issue with any of the phrasing - it looks perfectly well written to me. The exact phrasing was probably hammered out over many hours of negotiation by many fluent speakers of English; repeated use of the conditional, which carries overtones of *this is all somewhat provisional and speculative* is quite natural in the context.

---

<sup>1</sup> Both footnotes refer to comments on the later duplicate question, where this answer was first posted.

<sup>2</sup> Or, as per [StoneyB's comment,](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/28870/would-someone-please-tell-me-the-reason-for-using-will-and-would/28873#comment53564_28870) that the ongoing nuclear program is in fact "exclusively peaceful".

Answer (score -1):

"Will" has a more definite feeling of strength of one`s conviction about what they are saying.

"Would" leaves the door open for some doubt.