# Would someone please tell me the reason for using will and would?

Tags: grammar

The goal for these negotiations is to reach a mutually-agreed long-term comprehensive solution that *would* ensure Iranˈs nuclear program *will* be exclusively peaceful.

I am wondering the reason why there has been used the different tenses like the following:

Would

Will