# Usage of "will" and "would" in the same sentence

Tags: grammar

Can we use *will* and *would* in two separate clauses within the same sentence? For instance:

> 1. I *would* propose her if I got a chance, but I know she *will* definitely reject.
> 2. If absolutely necessary I *will* go to china, but I *would* prefer somebody from Head Office to manage it.

Are these examples correct or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why "would" instead of "will" in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17074/why-would-instead-of-will-in-this-sentence)

Comment: Not a duplicate; the answer in the referenced Austin is not directly applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is perfectly normal: there is no connection between the uses of *will* and *would* in the two clauses.

The first is less good. The first half is hypothetical (*would*); but the choice of *will* in the second half means that the speaker is now thinking of proposing as a real possibility in the future. I'm sure that people say things like this - effectively changing how they're thinking of it in the middle of the sentence; but I wouldn't recommend it in writing.

I would also make a couple of other changes, for idiomatic English:

> I would propose **to** her if I got a chance, but I know she would definitely **refuse**.

*Propose* requires a "to" for the person proposed to; and *reject* requires an object, so *reject it* or *reject me*; but *refuse* doesn't require an object, and is more natural here.

Answer (score 0):

"Will" and "would" cannot be used as substitutes for each other.

---

Have a look at your first sentence:

> I will propose [to] her if I got a chance.

The word `would` does not have a tense, but `will` is always future tense. Because of this, it is necessary to change `got` to `get`, which is future tense.

Comment: The OP is asking whether they can be used interchangeably, which suggests that the OP doesn't fully understand the difference between them. You could improve this answer by explaining that.

Comment: No. The OP is asking whether they can be used in **separate clauses** in the same sentence, which this doesn't address at all.